# Bulma Tooltip for FullCalendar event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, bulma

I'm using Bulma as my css framework and am having problems creating a tooltip on an event.  Here's my code:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    let children = element.children();

    if (children.length == 1) {
        $(children[0]).addClass('tooltip');
        $(children[0]).attr('data-tooltip', event.title);
    };
},
```

The code adds the expected class and attribute, but the tooltip doesn't show:(  Here's what it renders.  Maybe the class and data attribute need to be added to the span tag.  How can I access the span tag?

```
<div class="fc-content tooltip" data-tooltip="gas">
    <span class="fc-title">gas</span>
</div>
```

Comment: the span will be a child of the first element of your "children" array (i.e. it's the child of the element you're currently adding the class to). So I'd expect another call to children() might be helpful.

Comment: I expected that as well, it is not:(  The 'children' variable evaluates to an html string of the div with the enclosed span tag.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. `.children()` returns a jQuery array always. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ctg479zf/1/ . Here's the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/children/). But there's a much easier way to do this without having to tediously traverse down the DOM - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the class of the `<span>` is `fc-title` you can reach the element much more easily using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Find() differs from children() in that it will traverse down multiple levels of the DOM until it finds the selector you've given it, whereas children() stops at the first level down.

Demo:

```js
var element = $("#el");
var span = element.find(".fc-title");
span.addClass('tooltip').attr('data-tooltip', "XYZ");
console.log(span[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <div>
    <span class="fc-title">gas</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code example worked, meaning the correct element is now being modified.  Unfortunately, the tool tip on the event does NOT show.  I posted a full example here: https://bulma-fullcalendar-goof.azurewebsites.net/example.html

Comment: Well you asked specifically about targeting the span, which I explained. I'm not familiar with the particular "bulma" library you mentioned, so I'm not sure how much I can help with that. From what I can guess it might be something in the fullCalendar CSS interfering - e.g. to do with z-indexes, opacity, positioning, that kind of thing. You can see by inspecting the element in your example site that the tooltip is certainly added to the span, and you can see where it's supposed to be using the element inspector (in Chrome dev tools), but it just doesn't show up. Some debugging required I think